# When you select a specific field, output information related to that field ODOO

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, datatable, odoo

I am creating a table in the ODOO module, I have created my own view (table)
I have a table in which I want to implement the ability to choose what to display
For example, the user has selected the "identifier" field in select (select is in th), and it will display information about this identifier in the column
What can I do in this case?
I`m using XML, JS(JQuery) and ODOO

```js
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('.author_ids').prop('checked', false);
    $("th[class='author_ids']").hide();
    $("td[class='author_ids']").hide();

    $('.id').prop('checked', false);
    $("th[class='id']").hide();
    $("td[class='id']").hide();

    $('.display_name').prop('checked', false);
    $("th[class='display_name']").hide();
    $("td[class='display_name']").hide();

    $('.create_uid').prop('checked', false);
    $("th[class='create_uid']").hide();
    $("td[class='create_uid']").hide();

    $('.create_date').prop('checked', false);
    $("th[class='create_date']").hide();
    $("td[class='create_date']").hide();

    $('.write_uid').prop('checked', false);
    $("th[class='write_uid']").hide();
    $("td[class='write_uid']").hide();

    $('.write_date').prop('checked', false);
    $("th[class='write_date']").hide();
    $("td[class='write_date']").hide();

    $('.__last_update').prop('checked', false);
    $("th[class='__last_update']").hide();
    $("td[class='__last_update']").hide();

    $('input:checkbox').change(function(){
        var checkBoxClass = $(this).attr("class");    
        if(this.checked){
            $("th[class='" + checkBoxClass + "']").show();
            $("td[class='" + checkBoxClass + "']").show();
            // sessionStorage.setItem(this, checkBoxClass.checked);     
        }
        else{
            $("th[class='" + checkBoxClass + "']").hide();
            $("td[class='" + checkBoxClass + "']").hide();
            // sessionStorage.setItem(this, checkBoxClass.unchecked);     
        }
        $('div#Debug').text("hiding " + checkBoxClass);

    });  

    $('.main-item').on('click', function(){
        $('.sub-menu').slideToggle(400);
    });

    $('.field').change(function() {
        if ($(this).val() === 'id') {
            console.log("lalalala");
        }
});
});
```

````
    <template id="tableID">
        <t t-name="tableView">

            <div class="row ml16 mr16">

                <a class="main-item" href="javascript:void(0);" tabindex="1" >Открыть подменю</a> 
                    <ul class="sub-menu"> 
                        <t t-foreach="field_name" t-as="field" class="col-3">
                            <th>
                                <div class="menu">
                                    <div class="menu-box">
                                        <input t-att-class="field" type="checkbox" checked="checked"/>
                                        <div style="padding-left: 10px;">
                                            <t t-esc="field"/>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </th>
                        </t> 
                    </ul> 

                <table border="1" width="100%" cellpadding="5">
                    <tr>
                        <t t-foreach="field_name" t-as="field" class="col-3">
                            <th t-att-class="field">
                                <select class="field">
                                    <t t-foreach="field_name" t-as="colfield" class="col-3">
                                    <option t-att-value="colfield">                                       
                                        <t t-esc="colfield"/>                                       
                                    </option>
                                    </t>
                                </select>
                            </th>
                        </t>
                    </tr>
                <t t-foreach="groups" t-as="group" class="col-3">
                    <t t-set="group_data" t-value="groups[group]"/>
                    <tr>
                        <t t-foreach="field_name" t-as="field" class="col-3">
                            <t t-set="filk" t-value="group_data[field]" />
                            <td t-att-class="field">
                                <t t-esc="filk"/>
                            </td>
                        </t>
                    </tr> 
                </t>

                </table>

            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="/academy/static/js/table_checkboxes.js"></script>
        </t>
    </template>```
````

Comment: Have a look here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63013575/change-table-data-when-select-from-a-dropdown-value

Comment: Maybe Bootstrap could be enough for your need : filtering rows according to header input value : https://examples.bootstrap-table.com/#extensions/filter-control.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Bootstrap could be enough for your need : filtering rows according to header input value : https://examples.bootstrap-table.com/#extensions/filter-control.html

Otherwise, you could add an "data" attribute to your select tag and to the corresponding table-cells td, in order to filter or update them accordingly:

```xml
    <table border="1" width="100%" cellpadding="5">
                <tr>
                <t t-foreach="field_name" t-as="field" class="col-3">
                 <th t-att-class="field">
                    <select class="field" t-att-data="field">
                     <t t-foreach="field_name" t-as="colfield" class="col-3">
                     <option t-att-value="colfield">                                       
                     <t t-esc="colfield"/>                                       
                     </option>
                    </t>
                 </select>
              </th>
            </t>
          </tr>
          <t t-foreach="groups" t-as="group" class="col-3">
              <t t-set="group_data" t-value="groups[group]"/>
                <tr>
                 <t t-foreach="field_name" t-as="field" class="col-3">
                       <t t-set="filk" t-value="group_data[field]" />
                       <td t-att-class="field" t-att-data="field">
                           <t t-esc="filk"/>
                       </td>
                       </t>
                    </tr> 
                 </t>
            </table>
```

And Add some jquery onchange to the select tags:

```js
     $("select.field").on('change', function () {
     var select_col_th = $(this).attr("data");
     var selected_option = $(this).val();
     //var table_all_tr = $(this).closest("tr").siblings();
    
      //Show all the related table cells:
      $("td[data='"+select_col_th+"']").show();
    
     //Update all the related table cells:
     $("td[data='"+select_col_th+"']").each(function (index, elt ) {
                  var cur_value = $(elt).text(); 
                  //transform the value as you want and update:
                  var new value = "XXX";
                  $(elt).text(new_value);
             
            });

    })
```

Comment: "var new value = "XXX";" - what is this?
and why "cur_value" isn`t using in code?

Comment: Could you clarify which modification you need, when you choose an option in the select

Comment: When selecting, for example, the id field in the select tag, I need to change the th and td class to what I selected and output other information accordingly

Comment: i need somehing clear ... could you please provide 2 excel-like tables (including data)  : one before click and another one after click (with changed data)...?